# cocoapods 0.37.2 error during "pod install"

Tags: xcode, terminal, cocoapods, osx-yosemite

Im trying out the sinch sdk. I would like to use cocoapods with it. I went ahead and added the podfile to the directory my original project is in. when i run "pod install" i get the following error.

```
MIGUELs-MacBook-Pro:messaging miguel$ pod install
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-core-0.37.2/lib/cocoapods-core/standard_error.rb:88:in `message': incompatible character encodings: ASCII-8BIT and UTF-8 (Encoding::CompatibilityError)
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/claide-0.8.1/lib/claide/command.rb:367:in `handle_exception'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/claide-0.8.1/lib/claide/command.rb:315:in `rescue in run'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/claide-0.8.1/lib/claide/command.rb:303:in `run'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.37.2/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:46:in `run'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.37.2/bin/pod:44:in `<top (required)>'
from /usr/bin/pod:23:in `load'
from /usr/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
```

the same happens if i try to do "pod update"

What could i be doing wrong?

Any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 15):

ok, so i analyzed my "podfile and noticed the the (') were wrong. If anyone is facing this issue make sure that the correct is added infront and end of each library by pressing (control and ").

hoep it helps anyone out there

Comment: Thanks, just for clarity, the problem comes when uncommenting the second line in he automatically generated pod file to specify the iOS platform (default is 6.0). The (') are non-standard and you have to fix them.